# ScrollView goes to top when clicking on a text field, how to make it stay?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

A short question - how do I make the scroll view actually stay at its position (bottom), when I click on an EditText type of field? Right now whenever I click on it, the scroll view goes straight to the top of screen as if it wanted to appear above the keyboard.

See images for the exact situation.

Normal view:

[image: normal view]

Messed up view, the scroll view goes to top instead of staying at the bottom:

[image: messed up view, the scroll view goes to top instead of staying at the bottom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

set this to activity in manifest.xml